# using other adjectives with "more in number"

Tags: sentence-construction, adjectives

I wrote:

> If we try to cover these cases and achieve the same precision, we need to use **more and complicated rules** and this makes the wrapper more complex.

by *more and complicated rules*, I mean more rules, each more complicated..
did it convey the meaning I want, or is there other way to say this?

Comment: More rules, of increasing complexity?

Comment: @PerryW more rules in number, and each may more complex

Comment: @Cardinal - I don't think that's what Ahmad means, though; he means "more rules, and rules that are more complex".  Ahmad - **"more and more complicated rules"** is one possibility, although "more and more" is also kind of an idiom that just means "increasingly more", so maybe **"more numerous and more complicated rules"** is a better choice.

Comment: @stangdon he said **may** be more complex not each is more complex than the other. Thats why I think more and more is not a very good option

Comment: To cover these cases and achieve the same precision, the rules must become more complex, making the wrapper more complicated.

Comment: @TRomano this cover more rules in number too? Your suggestion is good, but I also would like to know how to combine "more in number" and other adjectives...

Comment: You can say "...additional, and more complex, rules..." or "more, and more complex, rules..." though the latter could be misheard and misunderstood to mean "increasingly complex", i.e. "more and more" instead of "more, and more, ..."

Comment: You can always say "must increase in number and complexity".

Answer (score 1):

Your phrase

> we need to use more and complicated rules

may not fully describe

> **more** rules and **more** complicated rules

You might use

> we will need to add increasingly complicated rules
>   we will need to add rules which are more complicated
>   we will need additional rules of increasing complexity

Answer (score 1):

That's one way of saying it - but a rather vague way.

Try 'we need to use more rules of greater complication' - if you don't want the sentence to change.

But you can always express it as ' we need to use a greater amount of rules with strong complications'
or perhaps ' we need to use more rules that are highly complicated'.